# Запрос для вывода имя ячейки (location.name) и кол-во доступных грузов (loads.loc_id)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Подскажите куда гуглить для решения проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что за проблема то?..

Comment: Гуглить JOIN и aggregate functions